# Is 2 billion cells limit per partition in cassandra, is this configurable to increase the limit

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am new to cassandra, from the documentation it is found that there is limit of 2 billion cells per partition. Can we configure this limit in cassandra. what could be impact on performance if we increase this limit.

Can any please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this limit cannot be configured and is likely an addressing limitation.

You wouldn't typically want to use that many cells in a single partition, but would instead want to spread your data load out across many partitions so that multiple Cassandra nodes would share the load.

For example, if you are collecting time series data, you might want to add a date field to the partition key so that each day would use a different partition.